# How to allow some keyboard events on menu items that are by default stopping the event?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, keyboard-events

I am trying to have a small form in my menu item. I have split button that has one item. In that item I have form: `datefield`, `textfield`, `button`, etc...

The issue is connected with some keystrokes such as **left arrow, right arrow**. This key events are supposed to hide menu item by default. Now I need to disable them since every time an arrow button is used in my `textfield`, it hides the menu.

I am using `beforehide` event, but cannot find a way to achieve to my goal. I could not find any events similar to **keydown** to handle this case.

One more key **backspace** is also used for editing the textfield, but this one redirects the browser.

**IN SHORT**: I want to be able to freely use the keyboard in my menu item's `textfield` without hiding it. Is this possible?

Comment: In your listener you could check if a textfield is focused and if so, you can stop the event bubbling like `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.cancelBubble = true`.

Comment: Don't do that. It's a very bad user experience.

Comment: @Alex Don't do what I am trying to do or what previous comment is saying?

Comment: Don't do what you're trying to. This stuff is way more complex than you think, and will cause you major headaches if you ever decide to upgrade the framework. Not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `enableKeyNav: false` in the menu configuration. From the [`doc`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-cfg-enableKeyNav):

> enableKeyNav : Boolean
>
> True to enable keyboard navigation for
> controlling the menu. This option should generally be disabled when
> form fields are being used inside the menu.
>
> Defaults to: true